# Зачем использовать @Output в Angular?

Tags: typescript, angular, frontend

Я новичок в Angular, и я не понимаю, зачем мне нужен @Output для отправки данных в родительский компонент.
Я пытался использовать @Input derective для передачи функции, как мы делаем это в React, и это работает.
Родитель:

```
@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     template: `
     <app-top-bar [func]="funcFromParent" [data]="dataFromParent"></app-top-bar>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  funcFromParent: () => void;
  dataFromParent: string;
  constructor() {
      this.dataFromParent = '';
      this.funcFromParent = function () {
      this.dataFromParent = 'Hi';
   };
  }
 }
```

объект-дочка:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'app-top-bar',
    templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css'],
    })
 export class TopBarComponent {
    @Input() func: Function = () => {};
    @Input() data: string = '';
    }
```

Пример дочернего шаблона:

```
   <button (click)="func()">ttt</button>
   <div>
      <p>{{ data }}</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: Переведи на русский.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в Angular есть название для потока данных: Input и Output - входные и выходные параметры. Что также является удобным для понимания того, с каким параметром мы имеем дело.

Во-вторых, у вас может не быть входных параметров в компоненте или директиве.

В-третьих, шаблоны в Angular подразумевают специальный синтаксис под события дочерних элементов, тогда как передача функции и обработка ее событий через Input потребует от вас сделать собственные обработчики таких событий. Таже не исключена потеря контекста.
Плюс, потребует продумать передачу данных в ту функцию, которую вы будете передавать в Input, тогда как Output легко поддерживает передачу аргументов.

В целом, Input и Output - это части фреймворка, которые дали разработчики, чтобы строить приложение согласно их идее. Если вы до этого пользовались другим фреймворком, то не стоит пытаться сделать из нового фреймворка - старый. Для каждой задачи есть свой инструмент и нужно использовать его.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим в  вашем компоненте есть два элемента - поле ввода и кнопка. И вы хотите, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, куда-то во вне, передавалось значение из этого поля ввода. Для таких случаев и нужен `@Output` при помощи которого внешние компоненты-слушатели могут получать необходимые значения.

Таким образом достигается разделение ответственности компонентов приложения. Одни - поставляют данные, а другие их получают и используют для своих нужд, третьи-десятые, например, - взаимодействюут с сервером. То есть, каждый компонент занят своим делом и все стремится подчиниться простым рекомендациям для создания гибких, расширяемых и поддерживаемых приложений ([SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29))

ts вашего компонента-поставщика данных:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Output() onInputData = new EventEmitter<string>();

  buttonClicked(): void {
    this.onInputData.emit(inputText);
  }
}
```

В другом компоненте:

html:

```html
<app-my-component (onInputData)="onInputData($event)"></app-my-component>
```

ts:

```
export class ServerCommunication {
  // Метод-слушатель. Вызывается при нажатии на кнопку в компоненте MyComponent
  onInputData(inputData: string): void {
    this.serverService.sendInputData(inputData).subscribe(...);
  } 
}
```